# Why react-frame-component iframe's body becomes empty?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, react-frame-component

Imagine, rendering multiple `iframe`s (using [`react-frame-component`](https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component)) and allowing users to reorder them.

Surprisingly, when `iframe`s are reordered, the `<body>` of one of them becomes empty.

I raised an issue [here](https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component/issues/170), but wonder maybe someone here would be able to assist as well since there is no much activity on the repo lately.

```
function App() {
  const [frames, setFrames] = useState(["first", "second"]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="framesContainer">
        {frames.map(frame => (
          <div className="frame" key={frame}>
            <Frame style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}>
              <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </Frame>
            <div>{frame}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="actions">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setFrames(frames => [frames[1], frames[0]]);
          }}
        >
          Swap frames
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

After clicking the button, first `iframe`'s `<body>` becomes empty.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reordering-iframes-bug-byn4s)

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue when using `react-dnd` / `react-beautiful-dnd` to do multiple iframe reordering and sorting.

The only method I found is to force the iframe component to rerender when the orders state update. However, the app could be extremely slow when all iframe update at once.